# How do i resize the image inside the div tag in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have made a Carousel in which 5 images will be displayed I want that the image should come in top and then the text and then a button. But only picture is coming I need to fix this.

I want to fix the image in the div card elements. This nature image is coming like this:

[image: this]

I want that this component should come like this:

[image: this]

```js
(function($) {
  var slide = function(ele, options) {
    var $ele = $(ele);

    var setting = {
      speed: 1000,
      interval: 4000,
    };

    $.extend(true, setting, options);

    var states = [{
        $zIndex: 1,
        width: 120,
        height: 150,
        top: 69,
        left: 134,
        $opacity: 0.2,
      },
      {
        $zIndex: 2,
        width: 130,
        height: 170,
        top: 59,
        left: 0,
        $opacity: 0.4
      },
      {
        $zIndex: 3,
        width: 170,
        height: 218,
        top: 35,
        left: 110,
        $opacity: 0.7,
      },
      {
        $zIndex: 4,
        width: 224,
        height: 288,
        top: 0,
        left: 263,
        $opacity: 1
      },
      {
        $zIndex: 3,
        width: 170,
        height: 218,
        top: 35,
        left: 470,
        $opacity: 0.7,
      },
      {
        $zIndex: 2,
        width: 130,
        height: 170,
        top: 59,
        left: 620,
        $opacity: 0.4,
      },
      {
        $zIndex: 1,
        width: 120,
        height: 150,
        top: 69,
        left: 500,
        $opacity: 0.2,
      },
    ];

    var $lis = $ele.find("li");
    var timer = null;

    $ele.find(".hi-next").on("click", function() {
      next();
    });
    $ele.find(".hi-prev").on("click", function() {
      states.push(states.shift());
      move();
    });
    $ele
      .on("mouseenter", function() {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = null;
      })
      .on("mouseleave", function() {
        autoPlay();
      });

    move();
    autoPlay();

    function move() {
      $lis.each(function(index, element) {
        var state = states[index];
        $(element)
          .css("zIndex", state.$zIndex)
          .finish()
          .animate(state, setting.speed)
          .find("img")
          .css("opacity", state.$opacity);
      });
    }

    function next() {
      states.unshift(states.pop());
      move();
    }

    function autoPlay() {
      timer = setInterval(next, setting.interval);
    }
  };

  $.fn.hiSlide = function(options) {
    $(this).each(function(index, ele) {
      slide(ele, options);
    });

    return this;
  };
})(jQuery);

 $(".slide").hiSlide();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

body {
  background-image: url(ur.jpg);
}

h1 {
  margin: 150px auto 30px auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.hi-slide {
  position: relative;
  width: 754px;
  height: 292px;
  margin: 115px auto 0;
}

.hi-slide .hi-next,
.hi-slide .hi-prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: black;
  transition: all 0.6s;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.hi-slide .hi-next:hover,
.hi-slide .hi-prev:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.hi-slide .hi-prev {
  left: -60px;
}

.hi-slide .hi-prev::before {
  content: "<";
}

.hi-slide .hi-next {
  right: -60px;
}

.hi-slide .hi-next::before {
  content: ">";
}

.hi-slide>ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 754px;
  height: 292px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.hi-slide>ul>li {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  left: 377px;
  top: 146px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  background-color: #333;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hi-slide>ul>li>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="slide hi-slide">
    <div class="hi-prev"></div>
    <div class="hi-next"></div>

    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
          <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/12125084/pexels-photo-12125084.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&w=500" alt="Img 1" />
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">
              Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
            </p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/405240/pexels-photo-405240.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=attractive-beautiful-curtain-405240.jpg&fm=jpg" alt="Img 2" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1784982/pexels-photo-1784982.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=attractive-beautiful-beauty-1784982.jpg&fm=jpg" alt="Img 3" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/219582/pexels-photo-219582.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=attractive-beautiful-beauty-219582.jpg&fm=jpg" alt="Img 4" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/247124/pexels-photo-247124.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=attractive-beautiful-beauty-247124.jpg&fm=jpg" alt="Img 5" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1808777/pexels-photo-1808777.png?cs=srgb&dl=attractive-beautiful-beautiful-girl-1808777.jpg&fm=jpg" alt="Img 6" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/754448/pexels-photo-754448.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=attractive-beautiful-beauty-754448.jpg&fm=jpg" alt="Img 7" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/761536/pexels-photo-761536.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=attractive-beautiful-beauty-761536.jpg&fm=jpg" alt="Img 7" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/761536/pexels-photo-761536.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=attractive-beautiful-beauty-761536.jpg&fm=jpg" alt="Img 7" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>  
</body>
```

Comment: Your Bootstrap and jQuery versions are both ancient. You should update both if you can.

Answer (score 0):

```
.hi-slide ul li img {
height:100px;
}
```

You can specify height of image according to your parent div.